# Make avahi advertise multiple machine

Tags: file-sharing, gentoo, afp, avahi

Is it possible that a single machine running avahi advertises other machines sharing files over afp ?

I have different machines running Gentoo but I don't want to run avahi on each server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the solution by trying to tune .config files !

/etc/avahi/services/ contains *.services like afpd.services

- Copy the afpd.servicies to match each machine you want to advertise : *server1.service, server2.service, ...*
- Add the `<host-name></host-name>` tag in each .service

*.service :

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone='no'?><!--*-nxml-*-->
<!DOCTYPE service-group SYSTEM "avahi-service.dtd">
<service-group>
<!-- Customize this to get a different name for your server in the Finder. -->
<name replace-wildcards="yes">MyHostname</name>
<service>
<type>_device-info._tcp</type>
<host-name>myhostname.mydomain.com</host-name>
<port>0</port>
<!-- Customize this to get a different icon in the Finder. -->
<txt-record>model=RackMac</txt-record>
</service>
<service>
<type>_afpovertcp._tcp</type>
<host-name>myhostname.mydomain.com</host-name>
<port>548</port>
</service>
</service-group>
```

Restart:  */etc/init.d/avahi restart*